# Installing LetsEncrypt on localhost via Synology DNS server

Tags: server, dns, localhost, nas, letsencrypt

For developing websites I have setup a few virtual Ubuntu machines.
Every machine has its own local IP address with incremental last number (192.168.2.10, 192.168.2.11 etc.)

To access the webserver, I want to give each server a fake url, like: project1-dev1.com, project1-dev2.com etc.

I have setup a DNS server on the Synology NAS and when i access project1-dev1.com, it shows the webserver on the first Ubuntu virtual machine.

Since all of this works I want to install a LetsEncrypt certificate on the Ubuntu server.
To test if the Ubuntu server sees the right IP I checked it with this line:

```
$ dig +short project1-dev1.com
192.168.2.10
```

Which means the Ubuntu server has the right IP address.

To install a certificate I use the following code:

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

This code asks for which domain i want to install the certificate and since I added the fake domains to the virtual host, they show up in the list.

I select the project1-dev1.com but get the following error:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for project1-dev1.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain project1-dev1.com
http-01 challenge for project1-dev1.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: project1-dev1.com
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for project1-dev1.com
   - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem:
   NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for project1-dev1.com - check that a DNS
   record exists for this domain
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just impossible?

I am sorry for my long question but I tried to explain as good as possible what I did to get here.

Comment: In order for LetsEncrypt to generate a certificate, they need to be able to access the website. As this is a site on your local network, LetsEncrypt cannot access it. Instead, you will want to look up how to create a self-signed SSL certificate 

Comment: Thank you, I think i got it working. For my websocket server I need a privkey.pem and fullchain.pem. I cannot find these files. The only files i have are: apache-selfsigned.crt and apache-selfsigned.key. How can I create the needed keys for the websocket?